# Format Date in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have created a backend in TypeScript Node that communicates with a typescript react frontend. The model schemas for users are created with Mongoose and each user have a:

- First Name
- Last Name
- email
- Date of Birth
- Creation time

I need to  change the format of the date to "DD-MM-YYYY" so it can be automatically read in a defaultValue when a user is updated/edited.

#### Backend

**user.ts**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

interface IUser {
    _id: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    dob: Date; // Date of Birth
    created: Date;
}

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    dob: Date, // Date of Birth
    created: Date,
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

export { UserModel, IUser }
```

#### Frontend

**Edit.tsx**

```
<div className="form-group col-md-12">
    <label htmlFor="dob"> Date of Birth </label>
    <input 
        type="date" 
        id="dob" 
        defaultValue={moment(this.state.user.dob).format("DD-MM-YYYY")} 
        onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChanges(e)} 
        name="dob" 
        className="form-control" 
        placeholder="Enter customer's date of birth" 
    />
 </div>
```

The front show all the information of the user when I try to update it expect for the Date because the format is wrong.

It uses "2020-02-26T10:22:19.018Z"
It needs to use: "26-02-2020"

Comment: What you want? Please express briefly.

Comment: I assume `defaultValue` must be a `Date` object, thus try `defaultValue={moment(this.state.user.dob).toDate()} `. In order to change to format have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format Perhaps you have to use one of these: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/useful-calendar-date-picker-scripts-for-web-developers/

Comment: I want to change Date format to it is usable within the default value of html input field when updating a user

Comment: So I have tried using moment js with no luck:  

```defaultValue={moment(this.state.user.dob).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}``` 
I set the default value like this and format the date like the input field suggests. Anyone has any clues what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
[
     {
       $project: {
           newDate: {
              $dateToString: {
                format: '%d-%m-%Y',
                date: '$date'
              }
            }

       }
   }
]
)
```